# Foreign key without referenced columns specification

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, referential-integrity

I noticed in the [SQL Server documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174979.aspx) that the list of referenced columns is not a required parameter of a foreign key constraint:

```
<column_constraint> ::= 
    [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ] 
    {     { PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE } 
            (...)

      | [ FOREIGN KEY ] 
            REFERENCES [ schema_name . ] referenced_table_name [ ( ref_column ) ] 
            [ ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ] 
            [ ON UPDATE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ] 
            [ NOT FOR REPLICATION ] 

      | CHECK (...)
    }
```

If I omit the `( ref_column )` part, it seems to reference the primary key of the `referenced_table_name`. That is most convenient. However, I cannot find any specification of this behavior so I am cautious to use it.

Does anybody know whether it is specified anywhere?

Comment: I don't know why you find this convenient. Why wouldn't you just specify which column(s) you mean? This way there is absolutely no ambiguity (consider the case of a multi-column primary key, or a parent table with multiple unique keys, etc).

Comment: Agree with Aaron.  Be clear about your definitions.  (Also, specifying the primary key is more logically resilient when things change.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think it only works when the parent table has a primary key so it's not ambiguous. At least that's how it works in Postgres, I can't check SQL-Server right now.

Comment: @ypercube it may not be ambiguous to SQL Server in a case where there is a PK *and* one or more unique constraints, but it would be ambiguous to *me*. This just sounds like another case of "maximize productivity by saving four keystrokes and 18 milliseconds of developer time, at the cost of confusion for everyone else, forever."

Comment: But @discrete, while it may look convenient, it also hides the referenced columns in the FK definition. Explicit is almost always better than implicit. You can also not name your constraint and it gets an arbitrary obscure name from SQL-Server. Then when you'll need it, you have to look for it in the system tables. Why not declare it and choose the name yourself?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree. The option is probably there because it's (I guess) in the standards.

Comment: @ypercube You might prefer explicit over implicit but I strongly prefer configuration by exception. I do name all my keys - I find a value in that. I find no value in writing "(ID)" after every foreign key definition. It makes the code harder to read for me.

Comment: @discrete It's a matter of preference really then. It's somehow more elegant but it also does hide something. It may be clear to you and certainly the way to go if you are the only one to access the database code. In a shop with more developers (or future developers when you leave this), it's a different matter. At least have this documented somewhere, so the future reader/developer doesn't have a WTF moment (it's not something a lot of people know and even fewer use this.)

Answer (score 8):

The behaviour is not explicitly mentioned in any of the official SQL Server documentation I am familiar with, but the 1992 Draft SQL Standard (section 11.8.2.b) does say:

> If the `<referenced table and columns>` does not specify a `<reference column list>`, then the table descriptor of the referenced table shall include a unique constraint that specifies `PRIMARY KEY`. Let referenced columns be the column or columns identified by the unique columns in that unique constraint and let referenced column be one such column. The `<referenced table and columns>` shall be considered to implicitly specify a `<reference column list>` that is identical to that `<unique column list>`.

Translated, this means an implicit foreign key does reference the primary key of the referenced table. As others have mentioned in comments to the question, it is probably best to be explicit about the relationship though.

Comment: The rule is actually: "*an implicit foreign key references the primary key - **and only the primary key** - of the referenced table*". A unique constraint will never be eligible for this (it's the same in Postgres btw).

Answer (score 0):

If the Pk has multiple columns, and you don't specify the columns in the Fk specification, then it may get them wrong. I chased a bug for a while that turned out to be that the columns were wrong.  For example:

FOREIGN KEY (OneID, TwoID) REFERENCES MySchema.ForeignTable

was interpreted as:

FOREIGN KEY (OneID, TwoID) REFERENCES MySchema.ForeignTable(TwoID, OneID)

If there is only Pk, then leaving the Pk Columns off is no problem, and is not ambiguous.

Comment: It doesn't "guess" the columns' order. It takes the order of the PK definition in the referenced table.